# SQL Server : optimize TSQL query with XQuery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xquery, sqlxml, xquery-sql

In SQL Server 2012 I have a table with 1 row which contains a XML column - `XMLdata`. Size of a XML is around 10 MB. I wrote a query but execution takes around 1 hour. Are there any options how to rewrite query that it will work faster?

Structure of XML:

```
<Settings>
    <Group Name="A">
        <Group Name="AA">
            <Group Name="AAA">
                <Parameter Name="aaa">
                    <Value>test1</Value>
                    <Items>
                            <Item Index="0" Name="A"/>
                            <Item Index="1" Name="B"/>
                    </Items>
                </Parameter>
            </Group>
        </Group>
    </Group>
</Settings>
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    A.B.value('../../../../../@Name', 'nvarchar(100)') + '/' + A.B.value('../../../../@Name', 'nvarchar(100)') + '/' + A.B.value('../../../@Name', 'nvarchar(100)') AS BlockPath
    , A.B.value('../../@Name', 'nvarchar(100)') AS ParameterName
    , A.B.value('./@Index', 'nvarchar(100)') AS ItemIndex
    , A.B.value('./@Name', 'nvarchar(100)') AS ItemName
FROM 
    [table]
CROSS APPLY 
    XMLdata.nodes('//Item') AS A(B);
```

Comment: Did you try looking at xml indexes? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934097.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I rapidly increased the performance.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use more *focused* XPath rather than the notoriously inefficient `//Items` approach.

I tried this and get the same results, and a better performance:

```
SELECT
    BlockPath = XC.value('../../../@Name', 'nvarchar(100)') + '/' + XC.value('../../@Name', 'nvarchar(100)') + '/' + XC.value('../@Name', 'nvarchar(100)'),
    ParameterName = XC.value('@Name', 'varchar(100)'),
    ItemIndex = XCItem.value('@Index', 'int'),
    ItemName = XCItem.value('@Name', 'varchar(100)')
FROM 
    [table]
CROSS APPLY 
    XMLdata.nodes('/Settings/Group/Group/Group/Parameter') AS XT(XC)
CROSS APPLY 
    XC.nodes('Items/Item') AS XT2(XCItem);
```

The first `CROSS APPLY` gets the `<Parameter>` nodes - but with a direct XPath with any `//` inside it - and then a second `CROSS APPLY` gets the `Items/Item` nodes under each `<Parameter>` node.

Try this - how much improvement do you get?

Comment: I used `SELECT TOP 100` with my code and your code. My code took 78 seconds and your code 47 seconds. It's better but still to slow.

Comment: I added primary and secondary XML indexes and I rapidly increased the performance. `SELECT TOP 100` needs 3 seconds to execute.

Comment: @AljPra: OK, great to hear. My experience with XML indices was less than favorable - they did speed up XQuery, but they also bloated my database from roughly 1.5 GB in size to around 11 GB in size.....

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments, it's a good idea to create [XML Index](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/getting-started-with-xml-indexes/) on your column. You can also query your XML field as marc_s suggested. Combination of these two should give you a huge performance boost.